# SQLite vs ArrayList in Android App

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist, kotlin

I'm currently making an Android App which needs ~4000 records (each one with 5 strings). At the moment, the app downloads and saves a CSV file, which get parsed into an ArrayList. The user can see all the records (displayed in a listView) and filter them (I use a for loop with nested if statements). The app works fine, but I wonder if the performance could be improved using SQLite or other data structure

Comment: SQLite queries over indexed fields are generally faster than for loops.

Answer (score 0):

Performance for SQLite would be faster. Also, if you replace ListView with RecyclerView, performance improvement would be significant.

Comment: Would it be that significant? I'm currently using ViewHolder and recycling convertView when possible.

Comment: Well, you have to test for that to be sure; Using viewholder pattern would certainly blur the distinction though..

Comment: I just implemented RecyclerView. Although there's no noticeable performance improvement, I have more options now (animation and so on). I'll implement the database with SQLite and if it runs faster, I'll mark your answer as correct, thanks a lot!

Comment: use [room library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room)